# Changing the Image Source of a nested Image of a Button On Click in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a series of buttons that act as toggle-able items (with more than 2 states).  I have a single method managing the click even on all of them, but I also need to update the image contained inside each button to match it's state every time they get clicked.  My XAML looks like this:

```
<Button Name="Button1" Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" Click="OnClick_MyButtonClick">
    <Image Name="Button1_Image_Default" Source="Images\Button1_Default"/>
</Button>

<Button Name="Button2" Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" Click="OnClick_MyButtonClick">
    <Image Name="Button2_Image_Default" Source="Images\Button2_Default"/>
</Button>

<Button Name="Button3" Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}" Click="OnClick_MyButtonClick">
    <Image Name="Button3_Image_Default" Source="Images\Button3_Default" />
</Button>
```

I then have some C# in the back that looks like so:

```
void OnClick_MyButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string buttonClicked = (sender as Button).Name;

    // filterDictionary is a Dictionary which contains the names and references of every button.
    int thisFilterCurrentValue = filterDictionary[buttonClicked];

    if (thisFilterCurrentValue == 0)
    {
        thisFilterCurrentValue++;
        //Psuedo Code:
        buttonClicked.Image.Source = "Images/buttonClickedOnce.gif";
    }

    if (thisFilterCurrentValue == 1)
    {
        thisFilterCurrentValue++;
        //Psuedo Code:
        buttonClicked.Image.Source = "Images/buttonClickedTwice.gif";
    }

    if (thisFilterCurrentValue == 2)
    {
        thisFilterCurrentValue = 0;
        //Psuedo Code:
        buttonClicked.Image.Source = "Images/buttonClickedThrice.gif";
    }
}
```

The issue is that I have no idea how to reference the 'Source' property of the  element that each  Contains.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nested `Image` element can be accessed via `Content` property (with type cast):

```
var btn = sender as Button;
if (btn == null) return;

string buttonClicked = btn.Name;

var img = btn.Content as Image;
if (img == null) return;

img.Source = "...";
```

Comment: @mkautzm, fixed. I try to avoid multiple `as` casts, because R# tends to underline them as possible NRE when variable is used on the next line. So I rewrote it a bit